# How to prevent adding a new row after using RowValidating

Tags: datagridview

I got an issue and I know I can get your assist.

My form contains a datagridview and I am using Key Down to add a new row to the datagridview. The issue is the datagridview still adds a new row although the validation fail when I check data entered in a row. Following is my code

```
private void dtDetail_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{ 
    //if (allow_add_row)
    if (dtDetail.CurrentCell.RowIndex == dtDetail.Rows.Count - 1)
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
            dtDetail.Rows.Add();
}

private void dtDetail_RowValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)        
{
    // I do some checking and set e.Cancel=true;
}
```

Please advise if I can check error before adding a new row or any workaround in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are on right way. Just try to set e.Cancel = true without any checking, and at dtDetail.Rows.Add() you get an exception. Check your "some checking" code.